# Хотелось бы услышать оценку и критику скрипта на python

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

Хотелось бы услышать критику моему скрипту на питоне. Писал простой бинарный поиск на python:

```
question = int(input())
num_first = 100
def start():
  global num_first , question
  if num_first == question:
    print("+")
  elif num_first > question:
    num_first = num_first + 1
    num_first = num_first // 2
    print(num_first)
    start()
  elif num_first < question:
    num_first = num_first + 1
    num_first = num_first * 2
    print(num_first)
    start()
start()
```

Comment: Проверь на 10000.

Comment: [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: дополню комментарий от @dIm0n.вот [pep8 на русском](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html) или [официальной документации pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) следуйте этим правилам пока вы пишите код на python

Answer (score 4):

Хорошо:

- находит введёное число (до определённой величины, потом случается переполнение стека),
- "змейка" в названии переменных.

Плохо:

- использование глобальных переменных,
- алгоритм,
- рекурсия.

Общие замечания:

- много лишних пустых строк,
- это не бинарный поиск.

Comment: Пустые строки - это просто человек маркдауном пользоваться не умеет.

Answer (score 0):

Ну во-первых вы используете в вашей функции global, что не есть гуд. Лучше передайте эти переменные как аргументы. Во-вторых вместо рекурсии лучше используйте цикл. В третьих вместо `value = value +` используйте `value +=`, тоже самое с остальными арифметическими операциями.

Comment: тоже с `//=` и `*=`

Comment: Да, тоже и с ними